# Change format of text file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, text-processing

I have a file with many lines of tab separated data in the following format:

```
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
5 5 6 6
...
```

and I would like to change the format to:

```
1 1
2 2

3 3
4 4

5 5
6 6
```

Is there a not too complicated way to do this? I don't have any experience with using awk, sed, etc.
Thanks

Comment: Do you need an empty line in between 2 2 and 3 3?

Comment: i saw only space between `1 1 2 2`

Comment: How are you going to get experience with awk, etc. if you don't actually try using them? Either learn how to program or hire someone who knows how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way which allows for customisation

```
awk '{print $1,$2"\n"$3,$4}' file
```

For a line between

```
awk '{print $1,$2"\n"$3,$4"\n"}' file
```

although `fedorquis` answer with `xargs` is probably the simplest if this isn't needed

As `Ed` pointed out this wouldn't work if there were blanks in the fields, this could be resolved using

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2 ORS $3,$4 ORS}' file
```

Comment: nit-pick: the OP did say their data was tab-separated so in case there can be blanks in the fields and so you don't change the tabs to blanks in the output you should set FS & OFS, and while were at it it'd make sense to use ORS instead of a literal newline: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2 ORS $3,$4 ORS}' file`

Comment: @EdMorton Edited. I didn't use ORS as i was trying to make it as simple and easy to understand as possible as OP said they don't have any experience with awk.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to group your file in blocks of `X` columns, you can make use of `xargs -nX`:

```
$ xargs -n2 < file
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

---

To have more control and print an empty line after 4th field, you can also use this awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%2?OFS:RS); print ""}' file
1 1
2 2 

3 3
4 4 

5 5
6 6 
        # <-- note there is an empty line here
```

#### Explanation

- On odd fields, it print FS after it.
- On even fields, print RS.
- Note FS stands for field separator, which defaults to space, and RS stands for record separator, which defaults to new line. As you have tab as field separator, we redefine it in the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: +1, I'm sure there's a canonical question for this already somewhere but with titles like "change format of text file" it's quite difficult to find one! :)

Comment: Thanks very much! How can I add an empty line between 2 2 and 3 3?

Comment: Thanks a lot Fedorqui!

Comment: @TomFenech thanks. And yes, I agree! We should definitely look for a canonical and mark as duplicated the other ones.

Comment: `(i==2?"\n":" ");` Just a small precision: it adds an extra space after the 4th field. to avoid include a second conditionnal like: `(i==2?RS:i!=4?OFS:"")` Using OFS to be able to mention it as it can change the output separator without interfering with the input one (FS)

Comment: @Tensibai true. I updated with an another [hopefully more clear] approach and no trailing space. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
perl -pe 's/\t(\d\t\d)$/\n$1\n/g' file
```

Fed the above command's output to the sed command to delete the last blank line.

```
perl -pe 's/\t(\d\t\d)$/\n$1\n/g' file | sed '$d'
```